# How with a regex I can find if a string contains two specific characters and a dot?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I need to detect if a user enters in an input the characters `pl` and a `.`

Something like this `pl.68768768` this `pl67687678` or this `.6897987`

Get it? Whatever is there I should always remove `pl.`, `pl` or just `.`.

I was trying to do it with `.includes` like `theString.includes('pl.')`, but how can I do it with a regex so it is more dynamic?

Comment: Doesn't `theString.replace("pl", "").replace(".", "")` do the job?

Comment: I don't get how besided marking my question as duplicated, the guy also downvoted it. That is not fair.

Answer (score -2):

Basic reg expression

```js
function cleanPl(str){
  return str.replace(/^(pl)?\.?/,'');
}

console.log(cleanPl("pl.68768768"));
console.log(cleanPl("pl68768768"));
console.log(cleanPl(".68768768"));
console.log(cleanPl("68768768"));
```

[Visualize it](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28pl%29%3F%5C.%3F%2F)